# proxmox hardware monitoring (system monitor)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, proxmox

Is there any way to install hardware monitoring tool like *lm-sensors* on **proxmox VE 4.2** (was installed from ISO: https://www.proxmox.com/en/downloads)? Or maybe there is another way to monitor host's hardware (cpu/mb/hdd temp, fan speed, etc)?

apt-get result:

```
root@pve:~# apt-get install lm-sensors
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lm-sensors
```

Look's like proxmox use it's own repo, if so how additional repos can be added?

Thanks!

---

One more question: What monitoring system (with web-interface) can be used on proxmox? or some web front-end for lm-sensors

Comment: In 4.3 SMART monitoring was added, but it is not enough for me

Comment: You were doing well until you asked your final question, which made the entire question off topic because you're asking for recommendations on software. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. In addition, your question is not as especially good fit for SO as you're asking about general computer software, not code you've written or an application that's directly related to writing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to add repository if the Debian main one is present in /etc/apt/source.list.

Here is mine :

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib

# security updates
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib

# PVE pve-no-subscription repository provided by proxmox.com, NOT recommended for production use
deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian jessie pve-no-subscription
```

Just do `apt-get update && apt-get install lm-sensors`

Comment: One  brief question: what monitoring system (with web-interface) can be used to show cpu/mb/hdd temp, fan speed and SMART?

Comment: You can use things like PhpSysInfo but it's probably not a good idea to install it on your hypervisor because it's preferable to keep it clean.

Comment: You could use Munin, Nagios or another monitoring external server to watch temperatures. SMART values are already displayed in Proxmox web interface (node -> disks)

Comment: I decide to create Debian container and use **zabbix**, only zabbix-agent will be installed on host, anyway thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Netdata (https://www.netdata.cloud),
a free monitoring tool, easy to install.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and "[answer]" and their linked pages. Your answer really should have been a comment. Taking the [tour] will help.